# .NET How to resolve missing primary key in the context altough the fact there is effectively a primary key stored in database?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an entity which I stored in my database, these are the model classes and the code in `DbContext`.

Model class:

```
public class Question_Option
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Question_id { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Question Question { get; set; }
    public string Short_value { get; set; }
    public string Long_value { get; set; }
}
```

The code in databaseContext :

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Question_Option>(q =>
        {
            q.HasOne<Question>(c => c.Question)
             .WithMany(e => e.Question_Options)
             .HasForeignKey(c => c.Question_id)
             .IsRequired(false);
        });
```

When I try to register a raw of this table in database I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Question_option' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'

The table has been successfully migrated in database and has its key as you can see in this picture :

[image: picture]

I tried to add to add key to modelbuilding like this :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Question_Option>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
```

but the error remains the same. How can I solve this?

Comment: For some reason in the error says Question_option but in the code you have Question_Option. I'd check if the name in every place is exactly the same and there is no case sensitive problem.

Comment: Could you show us the complete column list (not only the constraints) in the screenshot? Thank you.

Comment: you were right @serfe, the problem was coming from this difference Question_option and Question_Option, the first is my request body and. the second is the model